# Подключить svg в элементе через use

Tags: html, css, svg

Использую такую структуру `svg`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
                <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 357 357" style="enable-background:new 0 0 357 357;" xml:space="preserve">
                <g>
                    <g id="arrow">
                        <polygon points="38.25,0 38.25,357 318.75,178.5" />
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
```

Подключаю так:

```
<span class="arrow-svg">
  <svg>
     <use xlink:href="#arrow">
  </svg>
</span>
```

В стилях указываю размер и цвет. Не отображается.

Как правильно подключить `svg` в элементе через `use`? И как можно таким способом сделать маркеры списка?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Использование `<use>`:**

К сожалению, этот способ не работает в IE, даже в 11 версии. Есть [скрипт](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody), который обрабатывает соответствующие ссылки для браузеров, где они не работают.

Будьте так-же осторожны: в Сhrome невозможно использовать фильтры на таких элементах. Пропадают и объекты с примененными фильтрами как изнутри так и на сам `use` элемент. Кроме того пропадают объекты с фильтрами из внешних файлов. [Этот баг](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212) они не могут решить вот уже 5 лет

```html
<svg height=0 >
   <g id="arrow">
         <polygon points="38.25,0 38.25,357 318.75,178.5" />
   </g>            
</svg>

Тест:

<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#arrow"/>
</svg>
```

Если svg во внешнем файле, нужно указать путь к нему:

```
<!-- `<use>` внутри документа -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <use xlink:href="#icon-1"></use>
</svg>

<!-- `<use>` во внешнем файле-->
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <use xlink:href="path/to/defs.svg#icon-1"></use>
</svg>
```

**Использование `<use>` и стилизация CSS:**

```css
.marker use{
   fill:red;
}
```

```html
<svg height=0 >
   <g id="arrow">
         <polygon points="38.25,0 38.25,357 318.75,178.5" />
   </g>            
</svg>

Тест:
<span class="marker">
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#arrow"/>
</svg>
</span>
```

**Использование `<svg>` как inline-изображение в CSS:**

Есть более кроссплатформенный метод. Маркеры списка можно делать так:

```css
.arrow {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20%20%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20%20%20viewBox=%22-2%20-2%2022%2044%22%20width=%2220%22%20height=%2240%22%3E%3Cpath%20d=%22M%2010,0%200,20%2010,40%22%20style=%22fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#CCCCCC;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1%22%20/%3E%3Cpath%20d=%22M%2020,0%2010,20%2020,40%22%20%20%20%20style=%22fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#CCCCCC;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1%22%20/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class=arrow></div>
```

SVG закодирован через encodeURI:

```js
console.log(encodeURI('<svg   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   viewBox="-2 -2 22 44" width="20" height="40"><path d="M 10,0 0,20 10,40" style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#CCCCCC;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" /><path d="M 20,0 10,20 20,40"    style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#CCCCCC;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" /></svg>'))
```

Полученное помещается в CSS таким образом:

```
 background: url('data:image/svg+xml,[код картинки]')
```

Comment: "элемент надо определять в <defs> а не где-то непонятно где:" суть в том, что я хочу разместить `svg`, например, в начале документа и, вызывать его в разных элементах по всей html странице. это возможно?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova Протестировал, вставил код в ответ, тоже работает. Что-то у вас не так, может где-то ошибка

Comment: а можно сделать маркеры списка инлайн стилем без кодировки? просто свг имеет другой цвет, я хочу иметь возможность задавать цвет в css

Comment: @MarinaVoronova добавил в ответ

Comment: спасибо, помогли разобраться. но маркеры не получилось сделать таким способом, придется картинкой наверное

Comment: @MarinaVoronova Вы попробовали скрипт?

Comment: скрипт подключила в хэд, а маркеры сделала так: `ul { list-style-image: url(тут код encodeURI)}` но с заранее заданным цветом. и его уже не поменять в css

Comment: Скрипт нужен только для первого случая, только для ie и других допотопных браузеров