# Множественные перспективы в одном SVG

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Возможно ли иметь несколько различных фрагментов изображений в одном `SVG`, или даже просто имитировать такой эффект с использованием особых групп?

Я хочу показать разные части потенциально очень большого SVG, но я бы предпочел избежать его многократного рендеринга. Есть ли какой-то простой способ сделать это?

Перевод вопроса: [Multiple perspectives into a single SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33224511/7394871) @TikiTDO

Comment: @ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224511/multiple-perspectives-into-a-single-svg?rq=1

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подключить svg в элементе через use](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646634/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-svg-%d0%b2-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-use)

Comment: @Crantisz вы не хотите пройтись по всему сайту и пометить дубликатами все статьи где встретите `use` и `SVG`  Ведь `use` это основная команда в SVG/  В этой статье идет речь, как показать отдельные фрагменты большего изображения SVG

Comment: @Crantisz и что теперь, вы написали один ответ решение с использованием команды use в SVG и теперь считаете, что монополизировали эту команду?

Comment: Ошибся, бывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это довольно просто сделать. Вы просто используете элемент `use`,
 как предлагает [Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson).
Вот рабочий пример:

```css
svg {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

svg#original {
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 450 300" id="original">
  <circle cx="225" cy="150" r="150" fill="orange"/>
  <circle cx="175" cy="110" r="25" fill="black"/>
  <circle cx="275" cy="110" r="25" fill="black"/>
  <circle cx="225" cy="70" r="150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="0 145 180 1000"/>
</svg>

<br/>

<!-- part of the original at the same scale -->
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <use xlink:href="#original" x="-50" y="0" width="450" height="300"/>
</svg>

<!-- part of the original at 0.5x scale -->
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <use xlink:href="#original" x="0" y="0" width="450" height="300" transform="scale(0.5)"/>
</svg>

<!-- part of the original at 3x scale (and using a different method to achieve the scaling) -->
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <use xlink:href="#original" x="-450" y="-255" width="1350" height="900"/>
</svg>
```

Перевод ответа: [Multiple perspectives into a single SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33228819/7394871) @Paul LeBeau

Answer (score 1):

Для автономных SVG есть элемент `view`, который вы можете использовать, чтобы отображать только части вашей графики. Попробуйте это в отдельном файле.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
    <view id="circleView" viewBox="0 0 100 100"/>
    <view id="rectView" viewBox="100 0 100 100"/>
    <a xlink:href="#rectView">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="blue"/>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href="#rectView">
        <rect x="105" y="5" width="90" height="90" fill="royalblue" stroke="#53c"></rect>
    </a>
</svg>
```

Просто нажмите на круг, чтобы увидеть прямоугольник и на прямоугольнике, чтобы увидеть круг.
Это также работает, если вы ссылаетесь на свой `svg` через `img`

```
<img src="your.svg#circleView"/>
<img src="your.svg#rectView"/>
```

Я обнаружил, что это не работает для встроенного SVG. Здесь вы можете использовать аналогичный подход. Вы можете просто изменить `viewBox` вашего `SVG`. В отличие от вышесказанного, `viewBoxe`'s можно даже анимировать!

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 460 360" width="200" height="200">
  <polygon id="triangle" points="100,10,450,350,10,350" fill="#52c" />
  <circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#c52" />
  <rect id="rect" x="255" y="155" width="200" height="200" fill="#5c2" />

  <animate attributeName="viewBox" to="250 150 210 210" dur="0.5s" begin="circle.click" fill="freeze" />
  <animate attributeName="viewBox" to="0 0 100 100" dur="0.5s" begin="triangle.click" fill="freeze" />
  <animate attributeName="viewBox" to="0 0 460 360" dur="0.5s" begin="rect.click" fill="freeze" />
</svg>

<br/>click on any of he shapes!
```

Конечно вы можете также точно использовать viewBox при помощи `script`..
Если вы хотите ссылаться на разные части вашего `SVG`, вы можете использовать `use` - элемент, как предложено в других ответах.

Прим. переводчика
Как взаимодействуют между собой `viewport` и `viewBox` - это фундаментальная основа для понимания процессов в `SVG` при отображении фрагментов бесконечного полотна `SVG`.
 Для расширения знаний по этому вопросу посмотрите [эту статью на нашем сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748).

Перевод ответа: [Multiple perspectives into a single SVG @Holger Will](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33229167/7394871)